How to Get a Pretty Good Order of Non-Table Articles For Scripting
I have come up with the query below in an attempt to replicate SQL Commands for non-table articles. I would much rather use dependencies. Does anyone know of a pretty good way to script out SQL Commands of a set of Views/Stored Procedures/UDFs/Table Types in an order which does not require multiple iterations or produce dependency errors?
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT      
        OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS ObjectName,         
        type_desc AS ObjectType,
        OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id) AS CommandText,      
        CASE 
            --WHEN type_desc='TYPE_TABLE' THEN 0
            WHEN type_desc='VIEW' THEN 1 
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION' THEN 2
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION' THEN 3
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION' THEN 4            
            WHEN type_desc='SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' THEN 5
            ELSE
                7
        END AS ProcessOrder
    FROM
        sys.objects o
    WHERE
        type_desc IN('VIEW','SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION','SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE')--,'TYPE_TABLE')    
        AND
        SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = 'dbo'
)AS X 
WHERE
    NOT ObjectName LIKE 'syncobj%' AND NOT ObjectName LIKE 'sys%'   
ORDER BY 
    ProcessOrder, ObjectName;


Use a Table Value Constructor to build a types order table, then JOIN it with sys.object. Not better, but easy to maintain.
Like this
SELECT      
    OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) AS ObjectName,         
    o.type_desc AS ObjectType,
    OBJECT_DEFINITION(o.object_id) AS CommandText     
FROM
    sys.objects o 
    INNER JOIN 
    (VALUES
         ('VIEW', 1)
        ,('SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION', 2)
        ,('SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION', 3)
        ,('SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION', 4)
        ,('SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE', 5)
    ) 
    AS T([type_desc], [type_order])
    ON
        o.type_desc = T.type_desc
WHERE
    SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) = 'dbo'
    AND
    NOT OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) LIKE 'syncobj%' 
    AND NOT OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) LIKE 'sys%'   
ORDER BY 
    T.type_order, ObjectName


Thanks for the tidbit.
